# Flyway Database Migration file is not getting picked in spring boot V3.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, database-migration, flyway

I'm trying to write database migrations using flyway. I'm using mssql server and spring boot V3.0.2. But migration is not working.I'm trying to create a new dummy table to check if the migration is working. But the table is not getting created in the database.
I'm using IntelliJ 2022. As I searched through the internet I found that intellij might have some bugs or issues due to which migrations are not getting copied in build folder. But i'm not able to solve my issue.

**Grabdle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version "7.15.0"
}
```

**application.properties**

## Enable Flyway

```
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.flyway.user=user
spring.flyway.password=password
#spring.flyway.target=SQLSERVER
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migrations
spring.flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V
spring.flyway.repeatable-sql-migration-prefix=R
spring.flyway.sql-migration-separator=__
spring.flyway.sql-migration-suffixes=[ '.sql' ]
```

**Below is the folder structure**

[image]

**V1__testmigrations.sql**
[image]

**I tried by configuring SQL dialect as well.Terminal and console shows no error or exception or any warning about flyway or migration**

**I was able to create a flyway_schema_history table with `./gradlew flywayBaseline`  using terminal. But nothing more than that**

Comment: The warnings in V1__testmigrations.sql are not related to your problem. Try running `./gradlew bootRun` to see if it works. If also not, should be a configuration problem in your project.

Comment: No it's not working with `./gradlew bootrun`. What I could be doing wronge.Can you help me in this?What configurations I have to do?

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea too. Is the `db.migrations` a folder name or a `db` folder with `migrations` here? Try opening a file manager and check it.

Comment: `migrations` folder is inside `db` folder.`resources/db/migrations`

Answer (score 1):

Rename your SQL script file to the Flyway naming scheme `{Prefix}{Version}__{Description}.sql`:

- `{Prefix}`: Default is `V`.
- `{Version}`: Single number or major and minor version numbers separated by an underscore.
- `{Description}`: A double underscore separates the description from `{Version}`.

E.g., `V0.1_01__init_new.sql`

See https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway for more information.